# How to sum up time in php?

Tags: php

How to sum up time in php.
For example I have this series of time duration logs:

```
00:10:00
00:30:10
01:00:50
```

The total should be 1 hour and 41 minutes
Here is my code:

```
$log_in = new DateTime($log->log_in);
$log_out = new DateTime($log->log_out);
$diff = $log_out->diff($log_in);
$total += strtotime($diff->format('%H:%i:%s'));
echo $diff->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: "Time" is not the same as *duration*. You want to sum durations I assume?

Comment: I would  convert all three to seconds, sum them up and display them again in the required format.

Comment: @deceze Yes. I just want to sum up time duration

Answer (score 0):

Convert the time into timestamp using strtotime() function. Then manipulate the time according your need and get result in terms of seconds.

Once you get seconds.
For Hour

```
   $hour  = $diff % 3600
```

For Minute

```
    $Minute = ($diff - ( $hour *3600))%60;
```